# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

помогите пожалуйста. Есть код

```
from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
import os

execution_path = os.getcwd() # путь к папке с проектом
im_path = os.path.abspath('C:\\ImAi\\image1.jpg') # путь к папке с рисунками
prediction = ImagePrediction()
prediction.setModelTypeAsInceptionV3()
prediction.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path, "inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5"))
prediction.loadModel()
predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage(im_path, result_count=5)
for eachPrediction, eachProbability in zip(predictions, probabilities):
    print(eachPrediction, " : ", eachProbability)
```

но программа выдает ошибку. хотя tensorflow и Keras установлены

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек ошибки (вопрос можно править, нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1516313/edit)).